# How to change material-icon on click event with angular2/4 material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have the following icon within md-tab-group:

```html
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of arrayOfTabs">
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
        <md-icon (click)="changetab()">close</md-icon>
    </ng-template>
    My Tab Content
</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I want to make it so that instead of the "close" material icon, change it to a "star" icon. How can I accomplish that through a click event on the icon for that specific tab?

Comment: Instead of Close , can't you just say `{{icon}}` and change icon value on click

Comment: Yes, that works, post as answer and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In component :

```
public icon = 'close'; 

public changeIcon(newIcon: string ){
    this.icon = newIcon ; 
}
```

In HTML

```
<md-icon (click)="changeIcon('star')>{{icon}}</md-icon>
```