# How to add icon value to MdIcon created by component

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to add a icon from component? I have tried followed code, but without success.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: '<md-icon icon="{{icon}}" class="md-24">menu</md-icon>'
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  public icon: String;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.icon = "menu"
  }
}
```

Gives following error:

> compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind
>   to 'icon' since it isn't a known property of 'md-icon'.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `<md-icon>{{icon}}</md-icon>` ? So the value inside tags is the icon you want to show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change material-icon on click event with angular2/4 material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580387/how-to-change-material-icon-on-click-event-with-angular2-4-material)

Comment: Not duplicate but strongly related

Comment: `icon` is literally not an input property of `md-icon`. https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api