# Change svgIcon property on mat-icon - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a **mat-button-toggle** and I want to change the icon when the button is pressed, is it possible to modify the svgIcon property? Thank you

```
  <mat-button-toggle value="left">
    <mat-icon class="mat-icon" svgIcon="Thermometer" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
```

I found this possible solution ([How to change material-icon on click event with angular2/4 material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580387/how-to-change-material-icon-on-click-event-with-angular2-4-material)), but the implementation is different

Comment: This may be a little late but hope it helps someone else:
<mat-icon svgIcon="{{yourCondition?'minus':'plus'}}"></mat-icon>

Answer (score 2):

Old question but new answer for people looking to seek knowledge.
The solution is pretty simple.

**NOTE: This is the way when you've included custom svg icons and are using the attribute svgIcon to load your icons**

```
<mat-button-toggle value="left">
    <mat-icon class="mat-icon" svgIcon="{{ iconName }}" role="img" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Note that I've changed your 'Thermometer' with '{{ iconName }}'. That is, I've made it bind to the local variable 'iconName' which you can set in your .ts file.

```
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
    iconName: string = 'Thermometer';
}
```

To get the icon to change, simply follow the solution in the link you've posted earlier but change the variable 'iconName' and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post to show how to use custom icons: 
https://alligator.io/angular/custom-svg-icons-angular-material/

Comment: The question was not about using custom icons, but making them variable and change them at run time.