# To change multiple icons onclick in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am using a simple `<mat-icon>highlight_off</mat-icon>`. I want change this icon to another on clicking this icon.

How can I do it with typescript?

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580387/how-to-change-material-icon-on-click-event-with-angular2-4-material) too, no result.

Also, after I change the icon I want the second click to change the icon back to the original icon. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change material-icon on click event with angular2/4 material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580387/how-to-change-material-icon-on-click-event-with-angular2-4-material)

Comment: The same link which i mentioned as not working,again u have given the same link@mast3rd3mon

Comment: no, i just flagged this question as a duplicate, which it is

Comment: They have used <md-icon> ,I am using <mat-icon > i,e material 2.

Comment: but the solution will be very similar

Comment: I have told that it didn't worked for me.

Comment: why not? did it error? if yes, what was the error?

Comment: Sorry sorry i missed the colon, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component:

```
public icon = 'highlight_off'; 

public changeIcon(newIcon: string) {
    this.icon = newIcon; 
}
```

In template:

```
<mat-icon (click)="changeIcon('anotherIcon')">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

---

### Update - to toggle between icons

In the component:

```
public icon = 'highlight_off'; 

public toggleIcon() {
    if (this.icon === 'highlight_off') {
        this.icon = 'anotherIcon';
    } else {
        this.icon = 'highlight_off'
    }
}
```

In template:

```
<mat-icon (click)="toggleIcon()">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Similar, yes. But I don't know why it didn't work for him... Maybe because of some missing "

Comment: its not similar, its an exact copy paste of the other answer. Only difference is **`mat`** instead of **`md`**. The better way is to give a link to the actual answer.

Comment: He already gave a link to the similar answer that didn't work for him...

Comment: Ya i got it, but how can i perform 2 click functions, means first time on clicking the icon i am getting another icon suppose if i clicked 2nd icon i have to go back to first icon, How can i do it??

Comment: You can even make it better if you use a boolean or an enum to handle the state and assign the icon value according to the state that you're in.

Comment: @Faisal now that it has more details, does that satisfy you that it's a similar answer and not an exact copy?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @Faisal too bad :(

Comment: You need to have a separate icon variable for each button to hold the state and a separate handler for each button click to change the icon for the right button.